# how to replace value of vector in map of vector?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, replace, stl

I am trying to change value of string vector to -1 in map of vector as shown in below code but it remains unchanged when I display the data.

```
map <std::string, vector <string>> amap;
map<std::string, vector<string> >::iterator it=amap.begin();
//it is iterator of map
 it=amap.begin();
for(;it != amap.end(); ++it)
   {
        vector<string> intvec = it->second;
          for(int j=i+1;j<intvec.size();j++)
      {                    str2=intvec[j];

                       intvec.at(j)="-1";
      }
   }
```

I want to place -1 in the paricular vector index for particular key of map.
Please help:)

Comment: `int y = 10; int x = y; x = 8;`  -- That does not change the value of `y` to 8.  Same analogy with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to change value of string vector to -1 in map of vector as shown in below code but it remains unchanged when I display the data.

That's because you are modifying a copy, not the vector inside the map.

The line

```
vector<string> intvec = it->second;
```

makes a copy of the vector and then you are modifying the copy. Change that line to use a reference type:

```
vector<string>& intvec = it->second;
//            ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11 you can use the `auto` keyword and range-based loops. This will do what you're trying to accomplish (although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this). Note that this will set every value in the map to "-1".

```
std::map <std::string, std::vector<std::string> > aMap;
for (auto& kv : aMap)
{
    // aMap has key value pairs kv.first and kv.second
    for (auto& str : kv.second)
    {
        str = "-1";
    }
}
```